# Adding elements with jquery on html document does not preserve the spacing-margin (bootstrap labels)

Tags: jquery, html, css, append, appendto

I have the following code and is giving me a headacke. I use bootstrap 3.0.3 and jquery 1.11.0.
When the code is written in html is written like this.

```
<td id="td_id">
    <span class="label label-primary">A</span>
    <span class="label label-primary">B</span>
    <span class="label label-primary">C</span>
</td>
```

and I get a result A B C proper format and margin between the labels.
After I press a button, I delete the content of the "td" node and I want to repopulate it again using jquery.

```
$td = $("#td_id");
$(list).each(function(key, value) {
    var $min_span = $('<span>');
    $min_span.attr("class", "label label-primary");
    $min_span.html(value);
    $td.append($min_span);
});
```

The elements are added but the problem is that I obtain ABC with no margin(spacing) between the elements.
I read on an article that is different if you write the spans on the same line or on different lines. I are written in different line everything is ok.

Does anyone had encountered this? I would attach a picture but I don't have points.. :(

Thanks for the answers

Comment: do you have tried add an `$td.append($('<br>'));` between `$min_span.html(value);` and `$td.append($min_span);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because jQuery append spans without addding any white space between them. Since `span` is inline element, whitespaces, new lines, etc. cause gaps between them. So you can mimic new line for example:

```
$td = $("#td_id");
var list = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
$(list).each(function(key, value) {
    var $min_span = $('<span>');
    $min_span.attr("class", "label label-primary");
    $min_span.html(value);
    $td.append($min_span, '\n');
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u5NAA/

The trick is to insert new line `\n`, tab `\t` or even just space `' '` after each `span` element.

Comment: wow man...you saved my day. I just spent 4 hours to search for a solution and didn't find it. I marked as an answer but I cannot vote it because I dont't have reputation. Thanks again!!